# Script for feeding data into Yahoo S4 (Now under Apache)

Tags: python, streaming, distributed-computing

I know that we have to feed data stream into s4.

My question is that the script generating the input stream (that has to be feeded into s4) can be in python or it needs to be in Java only, since S4 is a java based.

Here is the link of S4 website:
http://incubator.apache.org/s4/